# core-data. filter a nstableview

Tags: core-data, binding, nsarraycontroller

I'm pretty new to cocoa programing.
In a simple master-detail view I want to show:

```
+-------+ +-----------+ +           +
|       | |           |
| tags  | |   books   |     detail
|       | | (selected |   (selected
|       | |   tag)    |     book)
|       | |           |
+-------+ +-----------+  +          +
```

I have defined two entities:
**tag**, with an attribute *name* and a relationship *books*
**book**, with several attributes (*title*, *author*, *type*, *date*,..) and a many to many relationship *tags* (one book can have several tags, and one tag can have many books).

Then I define two array controllers (tagsArrayController and booksArrayController).
They populate the tables, and the detail view.

The value binding is:
**tags tableview column:** tagsArrayController arrangedObjects
**books tableview column:** tagsArrayController selection.details
**detail view:** booksArrayController selection.details

Everything works.

I want to use the first table (tags) as a filter for the books table: when a row is selected in the tags table, the related books are shown in the books table.

But, when no tag is selected, the filter should be *disabled*, and the books table should be populated with all the records. Instead, now when no tag is selected, the books table shows no record.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Well, finally I found the solution.
I added the method:

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
```

and then used de *setFilterPredicate* method over the *tagsArrayController*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found the solution. I added the method:

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
```

and then used de *setFilterPredicate* method over the *tagsArrayController*.